# TinyXML load string from file

Tags: c++, string, tinyxml

is it possible to load strings from tinyXML file to string variable in application because when I'm trying to do that I received some bugs.

```
if (fall->QueryFloatAttribute("particle_texture", std::string name_) != XML_NO_ERROR)
        return false;
```

the error is: "type is not allowed". Could you write any example of using strings?

Comment: You *have* called functions before? Did you use the type of the arguments then? You clearly know that you should not do that, as you don't do that for the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use type qualifier before the argument when calling function. You might want

```
if (fall->QueryFloatAttribute("particle_texture", /*std::string*/ name_) != XML_NO_ERROR)
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: alright but when I delete std::string and I leave only "name_", there is error: " no suitable conversion function from std::string to float"

Comment: @David. The argument doesn't match. You need to pass an argument with type `float` to it. (but AFAIK it should be a `float*`?)

Comment: yes you're right mate, I just noticed that but still don't know how to make correct string loading from document. Maybe you have any example or something it would be very helpfull for me.

Comment: @David. Sorry I'm not familiar with TinyXml. But SO is a Q&A forum, if you have another question, please describe it as a specified and concrete question, then we might be able to help you. Good luck!